# Capybara Select Not finding select box in Haml fourm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm learning testing and devise through building a test application. One problem I have (and can't quite find an answer to) Is this problem where I can't find a select box. It's a box to get the age of a user. Here is the select box code:

```
= f.input :birthday, as: :date, start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year - 90, order: [:day, :month, :year], :input_html => {:maxlength =>2,:style=> 'width:30%; margin-left:7px; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 10px; display: inline'}, :label => false, :prompt => { day: 'Select day', month: 'Select month', year: 'Select year' }, :required => false
```

And here is the capybara select code:

```
select("3", :from => "Select day")
```

Maybe I'm not seeing something or I'm missing something?

Thank you for your help. You guy's are awesome : )

Comment: not setting this as an answer because it's a straight up guess but have you tried select("3", :from => "Day") ?

Comment: Just figured it out. Thank you for your help milesua : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... I did select("1", :from => "user[birthday(3i)]"). It what was what the name was after the code compiled (I used fire-bug to find the name of the class).